# gnuplot svg blank space when output to PowerPoint

Tags: svg, gnuplot

I have a gnuplot SVG terminal. One issue that I'm facing when I output the files and import to powerpoint is that there is a lot of blank space especially at the Top, even though I mention that margin is 0.

Below is the example and the screen shot that shows blankspace when imported in powerpoint.

My question is how to remove blank space so I dont have to trimp or crop using another tool.

```
reset session
set terminal svg size 600,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10'
set output 'output.svg'
set view 50,10
set isosample 40
set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"
set zlabel "f(x,y)" rotate
set pm3d noborder
set palette rgb 33,13,10
unset colorbox

set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set tmargin 0

set log cb
set cbrange [0.1 : *]


splot [x=-2:2] [y=-1:3] (1-x)**2+100*(y-x**2)**2 with pm3d notitle

set output
```

[image]

Comment: What Powerpoint version do you have? I can't even import SVG images into my Powerpoint. Maybe my version is too old? Unfortunately, gnuplot puts a rectangle behind the image which makes it difficult to get the actual bounding box. But I would say that there is an automated solution using gnuplot and Inkscape (no extra file handling, just using gnuplot and gnuplot running Inkscape in the background). So, if you are interested, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The "set margin" commands in the form you show them are designed to describe the space between the x and y borders of a 2D plot and the edges of the page.  Their effect on a 3D plot rotated so that the x/y plot borders are not parallel to the page is non-obvious.

I suggest using instead a different form of the `bmargin` command that positions the bottom of the 3D view box at a specific screen location, followed by a scaling command to increase the vertical size by a factor of, say 1.6 or so.  The vertical scale operates symmetrically above and below the center of the 3D view box.  My preference would be to also get rid of the empty space *inside* the view box by repositioning the base plane to z=0.  The additional command and their result is shown here.

```
set bmargin at screen 0.4          # reposition entire plot upwards
set view 50, 10, 1.0, 1.6          # increase default vertical scale by 1.6
set xyplane at 0                   # remove space between base plane and bottom of surface
replot
```

[image]